# Why PGadmin cannot use \set clause?

Tags: pgadmin-4

```
\set beginning '2017-04-01'
\set month 3

select races.date, races.name, drivers.surname, results.position
    from f1db.races
        left join f1db.results
            on results.raceid = races.raceid
        left join f1db.drivers on 
            drivers.driverid = results.driverid
    where results.position = 1 and 
     date >= date :'beginning' and date < date :'beginning' + :months * interval '1 month';
```

This works well in PSQL. But I am wondering why Pgadmin4 cannot use  `\set beginning '2017-04-01'`

Comment: Because PgAdmin is not the psql command line tool. This is not postgres SQL (or PL/pgSQL) syntax, it's a custom psql extension, which keeps these variables at the client.

Comment: Because `\set` is not a SQL command, but a `psql` (meta) command